# Using PHP, HTACCESS & MySQL for URL

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

My site has pages like news.php, vidoes.php, products.php etc
The data for these pages are held in a MySQL database they have id, name, description and permalink
If a name is News Article Title or Boxing Match Video they permalinks would be news-article-title and boxing-match-video

Now on the news.php page there is a list of news articles and they are linked to read-news.php with ?id= and the article id beside it.
So a link looks like this www.mysite.com/read-news.php?id=2
On my read-news page I use a GET to get the id and then data for that article comes too.

How do change the links on the news.php page to come up as www.mysite.com/read-news/news-article-title.php and the URL to display the same when reading it.

I cant seem to find a tutorial that shows exactly what I need.
Any help please
Thank you

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208915/php-htaccess-mod-rewrite-different-length-url-segments

Comment: Hate to do this, but what exactly did you search for in Google? There are plenty of examples out there: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=php%20mysql%20htaccess%20pretty%20urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a .htaccess file (if you are on a Apache server and do not have access to the server itself, like in a shared hosting situation)

.htaccess is a simple textfile you make and place in the directory in which it controls the access, e.g. the redirection of URL's and has a lot of usable functionality.

With this you can have your URL's rewrited without the user noticing it.
Good for SEO purposes.
More info:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If you want a quick try, automatic generation is done at 
http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php